# How to map authenticated Nginx users to their own directory?

Tags: nginx, chroot, jail

I am writing a social networking site in C and serving it all up with Nginx.  How can I make it so that authenticated users go to their own directory -ONLY- where a user-specific index.html resides.  I am not asking how to populate the index.html with user specific directives, but how to lock them into their own directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
map $remote_user $profile_directory {
    default      $remote_user;
    ''           guests;
    pavel        admins;
    ivan         admins;
}

server {

    location /profile/ {
        alias /path/to/www/$profile_directory/;
        ...
    }

}
```

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables
- http://nginx.org/r/map
- http://nginx.org/r/alias
- http://nginx.org/r/root
- http://nginx.org/r/location

---

second example (see comments):

```
server {
    location / {
        auth_basic            "Please Login";
        auth_basic_user_file  "/etc/nginx/htpasswd";
        root /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/$remote_user;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very interesting.  What kind of authentication options could I use with this?  I assume that is where the $remote_user gets set, in the authentication module?

Comment: Yes, it set by http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I would vote your answer up but I am a new user.

Comment: I changed your answer only a little bit.  Below is my whole bare bones nginx.conf that works as is.  I will add back the rest of the configuration later, this is just to show the bare bones example

Comment: Your "the bare bones example" is very bad. 1. `map $remote_user $profile_directory {
    default      $remote_user;
  }` is just NOOP, that wasting CPU and memory. 2. `alias /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/$profile_directory/;` is a NOOP too, you should use the `root` directive instead.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  The two sections that you mentioned are not NOOPS.  They work and if I pull either out it doesn't work.  Can you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: In the (1) you assign value of the $remote_user variable to $profile_directory. Why? Variables in nginx isn't cheap, they evaluated each request. In this case you should just use $remote_user instead of introducing a new variable. In the (2) you use more expensive the `alias` directive instead of `root` (see docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias )

Comment: I've added new example.

Comment: The new example works great.  Now If I could figure out how to do this with auth_request, I would be done.  I have never really done cgi programming before.

Answer (score 1):

```
events {
}

http {

  map $remote_user $profile_directory {
    default      $remote_user;
  }
  server {
     root                 /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http;

    location / {
        auth_basic            "Please Login";
        auth_basic_user_file  "/etc/nginx/htpasswd";
        alias /var/www/sites/mysite.com/http/$profile_directory/;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my edited version, which includes my entire bare bones nginx.conf